# Undefined indexes when saving form to database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, undefined-index

I'm having a little trouble with a form i'm saving in a database.

Basically, I have a form with checkboxes, every checkbox is connected to a column inside a mySQL database, **when checked, and submitbutton is pressed, it saves the value from that checkbox, if not, it will stay empty.**

Everyting works fine and saves to the database, **but the boxes that are unchecked give the following notice:**

```
Undefined index: WBR in /var/www/vhosts/leadserver.be/httpdocs/LPRamen/insert.php on line 35
```

here's a piece of the HTML:

```
<table> 
     <tr>
         <td><input id="vlaams-brabant" type="checkbox" name="VBR" value="Vlaams-Brabant"/> Vlaams-Brabant</td>
         <td><input id="waals-brabant" type="checkbox" name="WBR" value="Waals-Brabant"/> Waals-Brabant </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>    
         <td><input id="oost-vlaanderen" type="checkbox" name="OVL" value="Oost-Vlaanderen"/> Oost-Vlaanderen </td>
         <td><input id="west-vlaanderen" type="checkbox" name="WVL" value="West-Vlaanderen"/> West-Vlaanderen </td>
     </tr>
```

And so on and so on.
The PHP Behind this is the following:

```
  $adds['nameCom'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nameCom']);
    $adds['name'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $adds['number'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['number']);
    $adds['email'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $adds['VBR'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['VBR']);
    $adds['WBR'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['WBR']);
    $adds['OVL'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['OVL']);
    $adds['WVL'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['WVL']);
    $adds['LIM'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['LIM']);
    $adds['ANT'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ANT']);
    $adds['LUI'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['LUI']);
    $adds['HEN'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['HEN']);
    $adds['LUX'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['LUX']);
    $adds['NAM'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['NAM']);
    $adds['NAT'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['NAT']);
    $adds['INT'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['INT']);
    $adds['BHG'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['BHG']);

    $adds['leads'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['leads']);
    $adds['akkoord'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['akkoord']);
    //$adds['Regio'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Regio']); 
    //Regio is geen string maar een array dus kan ook niet zo gedeclareerd worden
    /*$Regio = array();
    $adds['Regio'] = "";

    if(count($_POST['Regio']) > 0) {
        foreach($_POST['Regio'] as $key=>$value)
            $Regio[] = $conn->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    $adds['Regio'] = implode(',', $Regio);
    */
    // query voor INSERT INTO
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dataramen` 
    (`nameCom`, `name`, `number`, `email`, `VBR`, `WBR`, `OVL`, `WVL`, `LIM`, `ANT`, `LUI`, `HEN`, `LUX`, `NAM`, `NAT`, `INT`, `BHG`, `leads`, `akkoord`) 
    VALUES 
    ('". $adds['nameCom']. "', '". $adds['name']. "', '". $adds['number']. "', '". $adds['email']. "', '". $adds['VBR']. "', '". $adds['WBR']. "', '". $adds['OVL']. "', '". $adds['WVL']. "', '". $adds['LIM']. "', '". $adds['ANT']. "', '". $adds['LUI']. "', '". $adds['HEN']. "', '". $adds['LUX']. "', '". $adds['NAM']. "', '". $adds['NAT']. "', '". $adds['INT']. "', '". $adds['BHG']. "', '". $adds['leads']. "' , '". $adds['akkoord']. "')";
```

**Keep in mind, These are just snippets of my code, the total is way to long to post**

I know that there are several topics on this already but i've done the research and none of the solutions seem to work. If somebody could take a look at this and find out what's wrong, i would be most greatful.

I've also tried to set a standard value in the database if a field stays empty, that didn't work.
I've set the indexes on the database columns correctly as well, but i still get the same notice.

Comment: this is far too specific to your current problem for stackoverflow, and is essentially asking SO to debug your code. Please consider reducing your problem to a minimal test case that shows only the problematic behaviour and nothing else. I'm voting to close as too localised for now.

Comment: I only wanted to solve this problem because I could not find how to fix it, after doing the research. I'm new to stackoverflow, is it not allowed to post a topic that specific? I meant no offense by this question, and I’m glad there were people available to help me.

Comment: Don't worry, it just came up for review as being a bit 'Too localized' and I wanted you to know why we were voting this way. I'm glad you found an answer and made it work :) It is encouraged to ask specific questions, but questions that are only applicable to your particular problem should be generalised to be useful to everyone. I could see this was a genuine question, but it just didn't quite fit the Stackoverflow format. Have a read of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) to see what I mean.

Comment: If you generalise your question and think it should be reopened, don't hesitate to flag it up for reopening. Sadly, I can't help you pare the PHP down as I don't work with the language.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info brice. I'll be sure to keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox data will only be sent via $_POST if it's checked, otherwise the VBR key won't exist in your array.

You should check for it using the php function, isset().

```
$adds['VBR'] = (isset($_POST['VBR'])) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['VBR']) : '';
```

Comment: thank you, problem solved thank to your expertise ;)

Answer (score 2):

An undefined index message means you are trying to access an array index that doesn't exist.
When using checkboxes, you don't get a value set if it's not checked.

So, when you process the form, check to see if the checkbox has been sent in.

```
$checkbox_value = (isset($checkbox_value)) ? $checkbox_value : 'default value';
```

Comment: +1 for describing error AND checkboxes don't send when unchecked. Emphasism on the fact checkboxes **DO NOT** post back when unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined index: WBR in /var/www/vhosts/leadserver.be/httpdocs/LPRamen/insert.php on line 35`

You simply have to check if an array element is set before you use it, to avoid that warning.

```
$adds['WBR'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['WBR']);
```

can be

```
if(isset($_POST['WBR']))
{
    $adds['WBR'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['WBR']);
}
```

or

```
    $adds['WBR'] = isset($_POST['WBR']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['WBR']):0;
```